# Look up zipcode via telephone area code

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

Is there anyway I can find out the zip code of a person using the area code I retrieve from twilio?

There is a curl example in the link below but I need it in PHP

[Twiliodocs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-sub-domain)

Comment: do you have any useful link in converting curl to php?

Comment: See [PHP: Basic curl example](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) and [PHP: cURL - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: From what I know of the Twilio APIs, that functionality isn't available.